# Giving value to a constant so that Mathematica simplifies the answer without having to do the whole operation again

Tags: output-formatting

I am doing some nasty integrals trying to fill in a matrix, and to save computation time, I set my hbar to be a constant of undefined value, so the answer it spits out consists of a real number plus some number times the square of hbar, which means I should be able to ignore it and chop it off since hbar squared is very small. Essentially I want to tell mathematica to apply to the answer the value of hbar. To clarify, I don't want to define hbar and have it do the integration again because that would make the computation time too long. I want the value of hbar to be defined only on the answer I get from the integration, not during the integration.

Thank you!

Comment: I took at shot at answering this.  If you mean something other than how I interpreted it please clarify and I'll try again.

Comment: why not use dimensionless units? this is usually the way to go with numerical calculations.

Comment: @acl We were told not to use all physical constants equal to one. I tried it too and the integration takes a long time surprisingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are describing is well advised but it sounds like you just want the function of `$PrePrint`:

```
$PrePrint = # /. {HoldPattern[\[HBar]] -> 0} &;
```

Now:

```
17 a + b \[HBar]^2
```

> ```
> 17 a
> ```

If you don't want to apply this *every time* you can just do the replacement manually:

```
17 a + b \[HBar]^2 /. HoldPattern[\[HBar]] -> 0
```

> ```
> 17 a
> ```

Comment: I just ran across some of your code on Project Euler that greatly intrigues me. Love to have you explain it some time.

Comment: Is `HoldPattern` really necessary in the second example?

Comment: @Ajasja I was waiting for someone to ask that.  Normally I would not use it, but it occurred to me that it might be useful to a beginner.  You see if Hbar was also assigned a value then the LHS of the pattern would evaluate to this value, and you might replace more than just Hbar in an expression.  For example, if you do `a^(1/3) + h^2 /. h -> 0` you get `a^(1/3)` as expected, *but* if you first set `h = 1/3` you get `10/9` which might be quite unexpected to a new user.  Of course this situation would be avoided by a more experienced user but I thought it best to include this safeguard.

Comment: Aha, good point.